# Checking for installed background processes in my phone

Tags: iphone, physical-access

I came from Russia recently. The security officer asked me to open my phone. When I handed it over to them, I saw there was a black screen with Russian writing on my phone when the officer was checking it.

How do I make sure there is nothing running in the background?

Comment: how long did they have it? did they plug anything? was it rebooted? could you see it the entire time they had it?

Comment: Which OS is running?

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, there's no way to be *sure*, other than by getting a new phone and deleting any iCloud backups that exist of your old phone. Restoring your iPhone to factory settings is a way to be *reasonably* certain, but if they've installed something on your phone, chances are that they don't want you to find out about it or remove it.